# How to acces .mdb and return value from it using php

Tags: php, ms-access, oledb

I've a mdb file called `short_db.mdb` in my server which is placed under `wwwroot\db\short_db.mdb`,I have created a sample php script called `fetchmdb.php` to fetch values from aforementioned mdb i.e follows

```
<?php
$count =0;
$db_path = "short_db.mdb ";
$odbc_con = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
$constr = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" . $db_path . ";";
$odbc_con -> open($constr); //line  - 9

$sql = "SELECT top 5 `id`
        ,val1
        ,val2
    FROM `tbl_accounts`";
echo $sql;
$odbc_con -> execute ($sql);

$rs = null;
$conn = null;

echo "done";
?>
```

and this `fetchmdb.php` is also hosted into the same place where mdb file is located (`wwwroot\db\fetchmdb.php`) so both mdb and php files are under in one directory(`wwwroot\db`)

So, When I run my url(http://thesite.com/db/fetchmdb.php) getting following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Source:
>   Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers Description:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not use '(unknown)';
>   file already in use.' in
>   E:\HostingSpaces\medlabsi\remedyonline.in\wwwroot\db\mdb.php:9 Stack
>   trace: #0 E:\HostingSpaces\mysite\thesite.com\wwwroot\db\mdb.php(9):
>   com->open('DRIVER={Microso...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   E:\HostingSpaces\mysite\thesite.com\wwwroot\db\mdb.php on line 9

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue using [this](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10363037-How-to-connect-to-MS-Access-database-with-php-amp-DAO) solution